# How can I save javascript variable value in a file using PHP or any other language?

Tags: javascript, php, file

I would like to save a JavaScript variable value in a file.

For example,

```
<script>
    var ref = document.referrer;
</script>
```

I would like to save the variable ref value in a text file using PHP.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("ref.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($file, ref);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can include the javascript in your php script.

Comment: I suggest using AJAX to send the variable to a PHP script.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-do-i-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: there are many many Stack Overflow questions regarding passing data to PHP from JavaScript. which of them have you researched and why did they not solve your particular problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by --

1. AJAX : Using AJAX you can easily pass the JS variable to PHP.
2. GET/POST : first you have to create a form with a text box. Then you have to set the value of that text box from your JS code like `$('#id').val(ref)`. AND then you have to submit the form to a PHP page where you can get the value by simple calling `$_GET['data'] or $_POST['data']`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After reading your comment I learned AJAX and now I know how to post data to php.